# Limit on belongsToMany association with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I would like to know, how can I set a limit on my belongsToMany relations. I try to add limit, but I have this error :

> "message": "Only HasMany associations support include.separate",

I have 2 tables :

```
| peoples (id, code) 
| people-friends (fk_user_id, fk_friend_id) // fk_friend_id is an id from user
```

My request :

```
    await db.People.findAll({
    where: {
    id: parent.dataValues.id,
    },
    include: [
    {
        model: db.People,
        as: "Friends",
        limit: 2, // <--- LIMIT
    },
    ],
})
```

People model :

```
People.associate = (models) => {
    // People relations
    models.People.belongsToMany(models.People, {
        as: "Friends",
        through: models.PeopleFriend,
        foreignKey: "fk_user_id",
        otherKey: "fk_friend_id",
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to get a certain user's friends limited by 2 friends (which ones? You have to add an `order` option) you can query PeopleFriend including People model like this:

```
await db.PeopleFriend.findAll({
    where: {
      fk_user_id: parent.dataValues.id
    },
    limit: 2, // <--- LIMIT
    order: [['Friend', 'name', 'asc']],
    include: [
    {
        model: db.People,
        as: "Friend",
    },
    {
        model: db.People,
        as: "User",
    },
    ],
})
```

Don't forget to add associations from PeopleFriend to both People links.